# Show that $f(z):=\frac{e^z}{1-z}$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C\setminus${$1$}

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have $f:\mathbb C\setminus${$1$}$\to\mathbb C$ given by

$f(z):=\frac{e^z}{1-z}$,

how can we show that $f$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C\setminus${$1$}?

--

I understand that for a function to be holomorphic on a domain, it means that it is complex differentiable in this domain, but how do I write this mathematically?

Also, how do I incorporate the $\mathbb C\setminus${$1$} aspect into the answer, as logically it is clearly seen that $z$ cannot take the value of $1$, or else the denominator of $f$ would be zero, but how would I formally add this to my proof? Thanks!

Comment: $e^z$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$, and $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-z}$ is also holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$. The product of two holomorphic functions is also holomorphic.

Comment: Assuming you have proved $e^z$ and $1-z$ are holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$, use the quotient rule of derivation show that it is differentiable at every $z\ne 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you prove (or look up the proof of) a more general fact:

$``$If $g:U \to \mathbb{C}$ and $h:U \to \mathbb{C}$ are holomorphic, then $z\mapsto g(z)/h(z)$ is holomorphic on the set
$$U\setminus\{w \in U \, : \, h(w)=0\}."$$

In your case, we have $g(z)=e^z$ and $h(z)=1-z.$

It is well-known that $g$ is holomorphic everywhere on $\mathbb{C}.$

It is easily seen that $h$ is also holomorphic everywhere on $\mathbb{C}.$

The only point $w \in \mathbb{C}$ with $h(w)=0$ is $w=1.$

Therefore, by the above result, $z\mapsto e^z/(1-z)$ is holomorphic everywhere on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}.$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you only have to consider $z\in\mathbb{C}-\{1\}$. There are several ways to argue here depending on the knowledge that is presumed. What do you know about holomorphic functions?

The most elementary way is to check whether or not the Cauchy - Riemann equations hold and if the derivatives are continuous. (Which they are)